# Bundling JavaScript courses Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle js:1

Tags: bundle

I read anothers similar questions but i couldnt fix the problem.

Its a project for practice how bundle files.

The console show me:
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Its refers to the html content, like it cannot understand html code or somethin like that.

Please i need some help here.
I left you the repo to acces the files directly.
https://github.com/FEDEIZ/FT-M2/tree/master/05-Bundlers

Comment: I cloned the repository and executed the bundle, but everything seems to work fine for me... Could you share the steps you followed to execute and build the project?

Comment: I tried with the solution folder that i could get. I've done this steps:

1. cd ../07-React-Estilos/homework
2. npm install
3. npm start

And i get this error:

Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at module.exports (/home/fede/Downloads/07-React-Estilos/homework/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/fede/Downloads/07-React-

Comment: The error is much larger but i cant write it all...
Please somebody i'm new here...

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it thanks godddd!!

The solution that work for me was...

Change the lines in package.json file with the next info:

"start": "react-scripts" to "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"

"build": "react-scripts" to "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"

previusly i deleted the node_modules file and then i made the change and run npm install again

Thanks kaffarell !!